# Adding a range value and putting the sum to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table (Sheet1) with scores in Column C.  When I click the button, I want a sum to display in another sheet (Summary) in cell B2.  After clicking the button, I want the table to be deleted but the sum will stay in Cell B2. Then, I will continue my entry for another month and do the cycle.

Screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

My code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set myRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp))

Dim myCount As Integer

myCount = Application.Count(myRange)

Sheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value = "=SUM(C2:C6" & myCount & ")"  '


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do a sum on the summary sheet of column c in Sheet1. Make sure there is a header on the Summary sheet for column B.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sum As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Set sum = Sheets("Summary"): Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

sum.Range("B" & sum.Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row) = WorksheetFunction.sum(ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Range("C100000").End(xlUp).Row))
ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: by the third line you mean the line which computes the sum? What version of Excel are you using? can you try again? I modified slightly, what does the error say?

Comment: Apologize, I incorrectly set the sheet1, I also included some extra code in the sum line.

Comment: Yes the third line. Here's the error: Run-time error '1004'
Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed   I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: I have tested the code above and it is working, it was bugging.

Comment: The error is now gone,however it doesn't do the sum. When I click the button the table is gone (which is what I really want)..

Comment: The sum should be working now, I was inputting the last row of the summary sheet rather than sheet1 and this was causing a 0 value.

Comment: @Lowpar..Thank you so much that works fine now..Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem Kurt, you should focus on creating the last row and setting your sheets as objects, makes life easier, that being said your initial code was good work. Incidentally, notice how you tried to set a formula as a value, I used a worksheet function because you wanted to delete the data, nevertheless, if you wanted to use a formula you should use: Sheets("Summary").Range("B2").formula = "=SUM(C2:C" & myCount & ")"

Comment: I play with it and understand.I have a question, Is there a way that macro will only delete the selected table not the entire row..I notice that it will also delete any data in the same rows

Comment: I am sure it can, however what precisely do you need? what is the entire row it delete?

Comment: try it now? let me know

Comment: @Lowpar nice answer and explanation in your comments, you could make it short and easier fully using the capabilities of the `Range` object. Instead of `sum.Range("B" & sum.Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row)`, you can simply use `sum.Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Comment: Hi Lowpar..I modified my worksheet, this time I added a formula, is there a way that the formula will stay there and will just delete the text in that table. tnx.